# Multiple conditional template specialization c++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a struct

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct foo {static const int type = 0;};
```

I want the implementation to be different when both `A` and `B` are arithmetic. However this did not work.

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_arithmetic<A>::value && 
        std::is_arithmetic<B>::value, bool>::type = 0>
struct foo<A, B> {static const int type = 1;}
```

I get the compiler error `default template arguments may not be used in partial specializations`. So how can I make this work?

One thing to keep in mind is that I also want to have other simpler template specializations that might look like this.

```
template <>
struct foo<string, vector<int>> {static const int type = 2;}
```

In summary, I want the first definition to be like a default, and then define a bunch of specialized implementations, one of which is kind of general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define the [primary template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template), [partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) and [full specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) separately like

```
// the primary template
template <typename A, typename B, typename = void>
struct foo {static const int type = 0;};

// the partial specialization
template <typename A, typename B>
struct foo<A, B, typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_arithmetic<A>::value && 
        std::is_arithmetic<B>::value>::type> {static const int type = 1;};

// the full specialization
template <>
struct foo<string, vector<int>, void> {static const int type = 2;};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pkNVxODQZMDaidLR)